# mixed content security warning in IE tab

Tags: internet-explorer, tabs, facebook-page

I am designing a facebook tab for pages which will let a user add any url which will then be shown as an iframe. If a url which is given with http and doesnt have valid ssl certificates to show an https version, this url throws mixed content warning on IE 8/ IE 9. Is there any way that I can fix it on the web application end?

This only happens for users with ssl security activated on their FB

Comment: When the user demands to use https, yet you try to serve them http content to their browser.  I think that is not very nice of your app.  To solve, don't allow non-https iframe urls to be entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to fix this on application end other than serving all resources over HTTPS.

User will be notified about mixed content if any content on page (served with HTTPS) located on non secure (https scheme) URL, this notification will or will not be triggered according on browser settings. Any resource is subject of these rules applied: images, scripts, stylesheets, iframes are not exclusion to this.

Comment: The external url given by user cannot necessarily be https.

Comment: Than you are out of luck and your users will see mixed content notification